# Looking for probably a persian/arabic/algerian song

Tags: live-music

I am not a native Arabic/Persian speaker, so pardon me for badly recognizing a song that I used to listen to on youtube years back. Probably 5~7 years back, and I vaguely remember a few words, tunes, and the singer's name.

Probably the name of the singer (a female young girl) was "Shagufa Orifion". In the video she was performing live in some kind of a restaurant, and the song was something like:

"Nozi de noza nini, mero mohabbati tu, shaam e muna wali tu"

Does anyone know this singer and song?

Answer (score 1):

First of all! Persian and Arabic are 2 different languages.

she is شکوفه عارفیان (Shogoufeh Arefian) and she is a uzbak singer who lives in Afghanistan and performs many songs in Persian, Uzbek, and Russia

it's some link in youtube:

[Concert in Germany](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VifPNisJO4)

[Bandari song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxubN_wU9wk)